# spinner didn`t show up

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code, when the select changed, I want a spinner show up on the webpage. Then, after we finished the changes the spinner should be hidden.
But the spinner didn`t show. And when I comment  "img.style.display = "none";",
the spinner will be shown and never stop. It seems a little odd.

```
 $('#arraySelector').change(function () {
            var img = document.getElementById('MainContent_spinner');
            img.style.display = "inline";
            // do something here...
            dosomething();
            img.style.display = "none";
        });
```

Comment: What does `dosomething` do? You can pass a callback function to it.

Comment: call `dosomething` as async, after execution of `dosomething`,  set display to none

Comment: @AdamAzad, post the `dosomething()` implementation

Comment: dosomething() call d3.js and draw a chart in the webpage. I was plan to show spinner before draw the chart and stop after finishing the chart.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you should do is to use AJAX to check if the request is processing or not.
Try using this code:

```
 $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
                $(".loader").css("display", "block");
            });

            $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
                $(".loader").css("display", "none");
            });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. How can I make sure the code executed in the right order without using the ajax, since the dosomething() didn`t use the ajax, it just draw a chart by D3.js.